# Passport.js Google OAuth: Best Practices for Handling and Customizing Error Responses

Tags: node.js, typescript, error-handling, google-oauth, passport.js

I'm working on implementing Google OAuth authentication in my Node.js application using Passport.js. I have set up a custom error-handling middleware to handle authentication errors, but it's not being triggered when there is an error during the Google authentication process.

Setup:

```
// Configure Google OAuth strategy
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
  clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
  callbackURL: `${process.env.SERVER_URL}/auth/google/redirect`,
}, googleAuth));
```

googleAuth:

```
const googleAuth = async (accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: Profile, done: VerifyCallback) => {
  //Somecode...
  done(new Error('error...'), undefined);
};
```

callback:

```
  this.router.get(`${this.path}/google`, this.passport.authenticate("google", {scope: ["profile", "email"]}));
          this.router.get(`${this.path}/google/redirect`, this.passport.authenticate("google", 
                                                                                              {
                                                                                                successRedirect: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/auth/success`, 
                                                                                                failureRedirect: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/auth/failed`
                                                                                              }
          ));
```

How can I ensure that when an error is thrown in my googleAuth callback, the Passport.js authentication process redirects to failureRedirect in my defined routes?